# How to operate USE flags? Is there a master class on Portage or Gentoo?

Tags: linux, gentoo, man

What man pages I need to read first?

Comment: Have a look at the [Gentoo Wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Portage) (and `man emerge`, probably).

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding so far, USE flags denote the additional packages that are pulled when you download a package.

To quote the Gentoo handbook directly, the idea behind use flags is simple:

> When you are installing Gentoo (or any other distribution, or even
>   operating system for that matter) you make choices depending on the
>   environment you are working with. A setup for a server differs from a
>   setup for a workstation. A gaming workstation differs from a 3D
>   rendering workstation.
>
> This is not only true for choosing what packages you want to install,
>   but also what features a certain package should support. If you don't
>   need OpenGL, why would you bother installing OpenGL and build OpenGL
>   support in most of your packages? If you don't want to use KDE, why
>   would you bother compiling packages with KDE support if those packages
>   work flawlessly without?
>
> To help users in deciding what to install/activate and what not, we
>   wanted the user to specify his/her environment in an easy way. This
>   forces the user into deciding what they really want and eases the
>   process for Portage, our package management system, to make useful
>   decisions.

For everything you need to know to make effective use of them, please take a look at the following resources:

- [Gentoo Wiki, Portage Documentation](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Portage#USE_flags).
- [Gentoo x86 Handbook, USE Flags](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=2)
- [Gentoo Wiki, USE Flags](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/USE_Flags)